# Trying to run bitcoind gives Segmentation Fault

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

Trying to run bitcoind on Ubuntu 16.04 and have all the required libraries after following the guide in the Mastering Bitcoin Book. After building from source without any parameters triggered i get the following error:

bitcoind
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Apparently this is due to trying to access a memory index out of bounds however does anyone know how i might be able to resolve it?

Any help would be great :)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an issue for the GitHub issue tracker, not stack exchange :)

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues

Please include the core dump, and which version of bitcoin you built.

Comment: Sharing a core dump file isn't a good idea, because it might contain your private keys, and then anyone would be able to steal all your coins (or coins you might receive with that wallet in the future).  If you've already done so then you should create a brand new wallet and send all your coins there immediately.